# DW6 Fluid grid layout IE8 and lower connects mobile version

Tags: internet-explorer-8, responsive-design

I am working on a website with fluid grids in DW, of course i am having problem with IE compatibility, IE9 and 10 works great but when it comes to IE8 and lower browser reads mobile version CSS. I tried to add a code in head section to redirect a different version but still couldn't achieve.

Original website is

http://thehouseofseven.com/ottima/index.html

and redirect to this

http://thehouseofseven.com/ottima/indexie.html

I would appreciate any help.

Have a shiny day

```
    <!doctype html>

<!--[if lte IE 8]>
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;       url=http://thehouseofseven.com/ottima/indexie.html>
<![endif]-->

<!--[if lt IE 7]> <html class="ie6 oldie"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>    <html class="ie7 oldie"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>    <html class="ie8 oldie"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!-->
<html class="">
<!--<![endif]-->
<head>
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<title> Ottima Wellness and Ingtegrative Medicine Center | North America’s premier
```

Integrative Medicine Center

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do the trick for the redirection:

```
<!--[if lte IE 8]>
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.location = "http://thehouseofseven.com/ottima/indexie.html";
</script>
<![endif]-->
```

As I'm sure you know, IE<9 doesn't do media queries, so that's the root of the problem. Since you have a responsive site for the rest of the world, you **may** still be able to whip IE8 and IE7 into shape.

Polyfills are availabe which will often make older versions of IE understand media queries. I've had good success with [Respond.js](https://github.com/scottjehl/Respond), and the other most popular option is [css3-mediaqueries.js](http://code.google.com/p/css3-mediaqueries-js/)

I usually call respond.js with a conditional comment like this in the head of the page:

```
<!--[if (lt IE 9) & (!IEMobile)]>
<script src="/path-to/respond.min.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
```

Good luck!

Comment: Direction works perfectly thank you so much...I will implement the other code you give as well lets see how it goes..

Comment: Thanks @Dilge, I'm pleased this helped

Answer (score -1):

one of the solution that I found is to create the stylesheet for IE8

i added .ie8 as in name of my class

example:

.ie8 .gridContainer.clearfix .fluid.logo #logo {

```
width: 174px;

height: 76px;
```

}

Comment: please add more detail or post it as comment